# While loop doesn't end python

Tags: python

After the function options has finished the while loop still continues even after update is the same as one of the strings it is required to be. How can I stop the while loop after the conditions for update have been met

```
while update.lower() != "tests" or "lessons" or "adjust":
     update = input("Do you want to update content from 'lessons' or 'tests'. Or do you want to 'adjust' what you aren't confident with. respond with 'adjust' 'lesson' or 'tests'").lower()

     if update.lower() == "tests" or "lessons" or "adjust":
         options()
```

Comment: The condition `update.lower() != "tests" or "lessons" or "adjust"` is equal to `(update.lower() != "tests") or "lessons" or "adjust"`. Think about that for a little while.

Answer (score 4):

You need

```
while update.lower() not in ["tests", "lessons", "adjust"]
```

What you have written is parsed as

```
{update.lower() != "tests"} OR {"lessons"} OR {"adjust"}
```

(where the brackets are just there to show how the language groups the terms)

A condition consisting of a non-empty string is *always true* in python, so the "lessons" part will always be true, and the `while` loop will never.

Answer (score 2):

Its because `or`s in your code doesn't work as you think they work, in your example they are interpreted as different conditions `update.lower() != "tests"`, `lessons` and `adjust` and so last two are always treated as `True` so this loop will never end. Instead you should do:

```
while update.lower() not in ["tests", "lessons", "adjust"]:
     update = input("Do you want to update content from 'lessons' or 'tests'. Or do you want to 'adjust' what you aren't confident with. respond with 'adjust' 'lesson' or 'tests'").lower()

     if update.lower() in ["tests", "lessons", "adjust"]:
         options()
```